# Rotating BufferedImage changes its colors

Tags: java, bufferedimage, image-rotation, affinetransform, seam-carving

I'm trying to code a class to seam carve images in x and y direction. The x direction is working, and to reduce the y direction I thought about simply rotating the image 90° and run the same code over the already rescaled image (in x direction only) and after that, rotate it back to its initial state.

I found something with `AffineTransform` and tried it. It actually produced a rotated image, but messed up the colors and I don't know why.

This is all the code:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class example {
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here

    BufferedImage imgIn = ImageIO.read(new File("landscape.jpg"));
    BufferedImage imgIn2 = imgIn;

    AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();
    tx.rotate(Math.PI/2, imgIn2.getWidth() / 2, imgIn2.getHeight() / 2);//(radian,arbit_X,arbit_Y)

    AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
    BufferedImage last = op.filter(imgIn2, null);//(sourse,destination)
    ImageIO.write(last, "JPEG", new File("distortedColors.jpg"));
}
```

}

Just alter the filename in
`BufferedImage imgIn = ImageIO.read(new File("landscape.jpg"));` and try it.

When executed, you get 4 images: a heatmap, an image with seams in it and a rescaled image. The last image is a test to see if the rotation worked and it should show a rotated image but with distorted colors...

Help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Did you debug to make sure you're not writing the wrong data to that final image? Did you make sure to use the same color settings (color space etc.)? Also please post a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that's too much code IMO.

Comment: How did itt mess up the colors? Did it get blurry or changed colors like all green got pink and so? Maybe you could show your images.

Comment: Sure, let me edit it really quick!

Comment: I did use the debuger but could not find the error...

Comment: @Thomas I shortened the code for better understanding

Comment: I assume your shortened code produces the same erroneous result. In that case can you please try writing a new image without transforming (or with an identity transform which does nothing)? If you still get the error (I assume so) please check the color space of your input and output images. I assume one is CMYK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there's a color conversion happening due to passing `null` to  `op.filter(imgIn2, null);`.

If you change it like that it should work:

```
BufferedImage last = new BufferedImage( imgIn2.getWidth(), imgIn2.getHeight(), imgIn2.getType() );
op.filter(imgIn2, last );
```

Comment: Works, gonna reread the documentation of AffineTransformOP to find my error. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with the `AffineTransformOp` You need :

```
AffineTransformOp.TYPE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR
```

instead of the BILINEAR you have now.

Second paragraph from documentation hints towards this.

> This class uses an affine transform to perform a linear mapping from
>   2D coordinates in the source image or Raster to 2D coordinates in the
>   destination image or Raster. The type of interpolation that is used is
>   specified through a constructor, either by a RenderingHints object or
>   by one of the integer interpolation types defined in this class. If a
>   RenderingHints object is specified in the constructor, the
>   interpolation hint and the rendering quality hint are used to set the
>   interpolation type for this operation.
>
> The color rendering hint and
>   the dithering hint can be used when color conversion is required. Note
>   that the following constraints have to be met: The source and
>   destination must be different. For Raster objects, the number of bands
>   in the source must be equal to the number of bands in the destination.

So this works

```
AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on what bhavya said...

Keep it simple and you should use the dimensions expected from the operation:

```
AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(transform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);
BufferedImage destinationImage = op.filter(bImage, op.createCompatibleDestImage(bImage, null));
```